# how to align a grid item center in material-ui in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a grid element with maxWidth so that it has horizontal margin when displayed in a big screen. I want the grid element to be centered and a long paragraph should be aligned to the left side. How would you do? I'm using MUI v5. Thank you.

```
 <Box
      style={{
        backgroundColor:"rgb(234, 237, 242)"
      }}      
    >
      <Grid container alignItems='center' justifyContent='center' maxWidth='md'>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={12} justifyContent="center">   
            <Typography align="center" variant="h4" style={{ fontWeight: 800 }} sx={{mb:4}}>
              Nice title
          </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{ px: 4 }} paragraph>very very long line. very very long line. very very long line. very very long line. very very long line. very very long line. very very long line. very very long line. very very long line. very very long line. very very long line.</Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid> 
    </Box>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @watanabe.N ,just need to add `textAlign: 'center'` in Box style and you good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple enough using [system properties](https://mui.com/system/properties/).

```
    <Box
      display="flex"
      justifyContent="center"
      style={{
        backgroundColor:"rgb(234, 237, 242)"
      }}
    >
      ...
```

Comment: Glad that helped! Please check if you feel confident this is a correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following code. I have checked this code it is working perfectly.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));

export default function BasicGrid() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgb(234, 237, 242)' }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Item>
            <Typography align="center" variant="h4" style={{ fontWeight: 800 }} sx={{ mb: 4 }}>
              Hello
            </Typography>
            <Typography align="center" sx={{ px: 4 }} paragraph>
              very very long line
            </Typography>
          </Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work.

Comment: I confirm this code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fvrxpw?file=demo.js)

Comment: Thank you but a long text isn't aligned to the left side :/

Comment: Similar to title text set *align="center"* props to long text typography. I also updated my answer